# Upgrading Seeddms to 6.0.19 from 5.1.25

Tags: linux, debian, dms

I've done a bit of googling and haven't been able to find any documentation on this, but I need to upgrade my Seeddms (Document Management System) server from 5.1.25 to 6.0.19.
I am running a Linux Lamp 4.19.0-19-amd #1 SMP Debian 4.19.232-1 (2022-03-07) with a Seeddms web server on it.
I tried copying the contents of the .gz download file of the latest version over my current /var/www/html/dms/ folder and it didn't work, I did a similar thing to update my dokuwiki site so I thought I'd give it a try here.
I am still new to Linux so any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find the solution, in the seeddms-quickstart-x.x.x/seeddmsxxx/seeddms-x.x.x/doc/README.Install.md.

Here is what is says on upgrading versions if anyone has trouble with this as well. Make sure your server meets the requirement as well.

## UPGRADING FROM A PREVIOUS VERSION OF SEEDDMS

As SeedDMS is a smooth continuation of LetoDMS there is no difference
in updating from LetoDMS or SeedDMS.

You have basically two choices to update SeedDMS:

- you install a fresh version of SeedDMS and copy over your data and configuration
- you replace the software in your current installation with a new version

The first option is less interuptive but requires to be able to set up a second
temporary SeedDMS installation, which may not be possible, e.g. because of storage
limitations. It can be the only option if you change servers.

The first update procedure is only needed if the version changes on the minor
or major version number. Changes in the subminor version number will never
include database changes and consequently it is sufficient to use the existing
data directory and database with the new version. Choose the second update
option in this case.

In both cases make sure to have a backup of your data directory, configuration
and database.

### Fresh installation and take over of data

The first update option is to set up a new instance of SeedDMS and once
that is running take over the data from your current (old) instance.

1. just do a fresh installation somewhere on your web server and make sure it
   works. It is fine to use
   SQLite for it, even if your final installation uses MySQL.
2. replace the data directory in your new installation with the data directory
   from your current installation. Depending on the size of that directory (and
   whether the new installation is on a new server or the old server) you
   may either copy, move or place a symbolic link. The content of the data directory
   will not be changed during the update. Its even perfectly save to
   browse through your documents and download them after finishing the
   update. The data directory will not be modified until you actually modify
   documents.
3. copy over the configuration `settings.xml` into your new installation. This will
   effectively make your new installation use the data from your old installation,
   because all paths are still pointing to the old installation.
4. if you use mysql you could as well make a copy of the database to make sure
   your current database remains unchanged.
5. modify the `settings.xml` to fit the environment of the new installation.
   This will mostly be the
   httpRoot, the paths to the installation directory and possibly the database
   connection.
6. create a file `ENABLE_INSTALL_TOOL` in the `conf` directory and point
   your browser at http://hostname/seeddms/install
   The install tool will detect the version of your current SeedDMS installation
   and run the required database updates.
   If you update just within the last version number (e.g. from 5.1.6 to 5.1.9),
   this step
   will not be required because such a subminor version update will never
   contain database updates.

### Upgrading your current installation

Instead of setting up a new installation, you may as well replace the php files
in your current installation with new versions from the quickstart archive.

1. get the SeedDMS quickstart archive `seeddms-quickstart-x.y.z.tar.gz` and
   unpack it somewhere on your disc.
2. copy the directory `seeddms-x.y.z` from the unpacked archive into your
   current installation and make the link `seeddms` point to this new directory.
3. copy the directory `pear` from the unpacked archive into your current
   installation, replacing the existing directory. Make a backup of `pear` before
   the replacement if you want to ensure to be able to go back to your old version.
4. you may compare your `conf/settings.xml` file with the shipped version
   `conf/settings.xml.template` for new parameters. If you don't do it, the next
   time you save the configuration the default values will be used.
5. create a file `ENABLE_INSTALL_TOOL` in the `conf` directory and point
   your browser at http://hostname/seeddms/install
   The install tool will detect the version of your current SeedDMS installation
   and run the required database updates.
   If you update just within the last version number (e.g. from 5.1.6 to 5.1.9),
   this step
   will not be required because such a subminor version update will never
   contain database updates.